Testing phone authentication using appium
I am currently busy testing a Flutter app (was provided a release apk) using Appium and Android Studio, my code navigates the app but as soon as it gets to the login feature I get the following message
Error: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ Invalid app info in play_integrity_token]

